# controller class in php

Tags: php, http-referer

I'm new at php programming, and I want to ask question:

So I have 3 php forms:

- insertworkerform.php
- inserttoolsform.php
- insertorderform.php

Inside those files I used `<form action=class.controller.php>` tag
that will be used to control those file,
so i need to know which file the request come from, is it possible?
and then when i know which file use controller class i will call the method from another class corresponding to those 3 file request, is it alright?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you have 3 forms in three separate files?  You have one controller for all three so you want to know how to pass which file sent it?

try:

```
    <input type="hidden" value="NAME OF FILE">
```

Replace the value with the documents name.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Brown is right, here is another way to do it, only for learning purposes.

**Form:**

```
<!-- pass variable 'from' to the controller -->
<form action='class.controller.php?from=insertworkerform'>
```

**class.controller.php**

```
<?php
    // example, if you want to store in database remember SQL Injection
    $from = isset($_GET['from'])?
        $_GET['from'] :
        'I dont know which form called me';

    // You can do what you want with the var $from
    // like this
    switch($from) {
        case 'insertworkerform':
            // bla bla
            break;
        case 'another_form':
            // bl bla
            break;
        default:
            // I dont know which form called me
    }
```